# Remove constness of a pointer in a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, macros, constants

So I need to remove constness from some variables in C (I know what I'm doing). So I wrote a little macro (`UNCONST`) which lets me assign an new value to a const value. This works just fine for normal variables of types like `int`. But this doesn't work for pointers. So I can't let a pointer point to a different position using my macro `UNCONST` without getting an compiler warning.

Here a little test program `unconst.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNCONST(type, var, assign) do { \
  type* ptr = (type*)&(var); \
  *ptr = (assign); \
} while(0)

struct mystruct {
  int value;
  char *buffer;
};

int main() {
  // this works just fine when we have an int
  const struct mystruct structure;
  UNCONST(int, structure.value, 6);
  printf("structure.value = %i\n", structure.value);

  // but it doesn't when we have an char *
  char *string = "string";
  UNCONST(char *, structure.buffer, string);
  printf("structure.buffer = %s\n", structure.buffer);

  // this doesn't work either, because whole struct is const, not the pointer.
  structure.buffer = string;
  printf("structure.buffer = %s\n", structure.buffer);
}
```

compiling & executing

```
$ LANG=en gcc -o unconst unconst.c
unconst.c: In function ‘main’:
unconst.c:21:3: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
unconst.c:25:3: error: assignment of member ‘buffer’ in read-only object
```

Is there a way to optimize my macro so this warning doesn't show up?

Comment: Do you realize that you can just write string1 = string2 ?

Comment: @Kylo I didn't but it seems like I simplified my code too much, I need to edit the question.

Comment: The first segment using `int` invokes undefined behaviour.  The compiler might legitimately place `i` in readonly memory, and then you probably get a crash, or other unexpected result (like the `printf()` printing 5 instead of 6).  You're relying on a peculiarity of your implementation there.  So, expect problems when you switch platforms or compilers.

Comment: my 2c: if you need so often to "unconst" and then planned that macro... couldn't it be that there's something odd somewhere else?

Comment: For the occasions when I need this, I use `#define CONST_CAST(type, value) ((type)(value))` (in C; in C++, it becomes `#define CONST_CAST(type, value) const_cast<type>(value)`).  But I normally only use this to pass a value that's given as `const` to a function that is declared as taking a non-const value, but which does not modify the relevant parameter — so, the called function could/should be declared with `const` but isn't (usually for 'hysterical raisins' or historical reasons).  Assigning to `const` qualified variables is undefined behaviour, and non-portable.

Comment: the reason why I'm doing this is not trivial: I'm writing a string library which uses immutable objects. So i don't want a user of the code to change the values inside of a struct. So i defined the string struct as constant. But in my functions I (logically) need to change the values inside of the struct.

Comment: Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #4: The the OP says "I know what I'm doing", they don't.

Comment: @Mogria: Are you writing something like `strchr`? There *are* uses for const-casting, but they have to be legal. Your examples aren't.

Comment: Also, your example conflates two points. The first is `T *` vs `T * const`, and the second is `T *` vs `U *` (or perhaps `U * const`). The upshot is: I would strongly urge you to work out a *legal*, *representative*, *short* example of what you're trying to accomplish and redesign the question.

Comment: @Mogria: that type of thing is "usually" done with opaque types rather than messing with constness.

Comment: @Mat Thanks! this seams to be a good solution. Instead of this const  stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in:

```
const char *string1 = "string1";
UNCONST(char *, string1, string2);
```

is that `string1` is not really const, it can be assigned to, but points to an array of const characters.

Actually, doing:

```
string1 = string2;
```

compiles just fine.

Other thing is if you want to copy the array. Then I'd write your macro as this:

```
#define UNCONST(type, var) (*(type*)&(var))
```

And so:

```
UNCONST(int, i) = 42;
```

To copy the array of chars you could do:

```
strcpy(UNCONST(char**,string1), string2);
```

FOOTNOTE: actually I find this macro rather useless: I find:

```
*(int*)&i = 42;
```

as cumbersome as this kind of operation should be.

Comment: nice answer but the I used a code example which was simplified to much. So I edited the question. The char pointer is in reality inside of a `const struct`

Comment: FreeBSD uses this macro: 
`#define __DECONST(type, var) ((type)(uintptr_t)(const void *)(var))`

Answer (score 0):

If string1 is supposed to be a const pointer (instead of a non-const pointer to const data), write it like this:

```
char * const ptr = "foo";
```

or

```
const char * const ptr = "foo";
```

Maybe (I haven't tested it) your UCONST macro would work as you expected if you declared your pointer correctly.